# How to get rid of this reflection on falling edge of i2c SDA line?

Tags: i2c, signal-integrity, edge, reflection

This is the scopeshot of the falling edge:

[image]

How to get rid of the reflections on the falling edge of this SDA line?

Comment: It doesn't look like it should be a problem so why bother?

Comment: why couldnt this be a problem? That reflection - couldnt it be interpreted as an extra high cycle on the SDA?

Comment: Where is that reflection you are so worried about, you mean that first irregularity from let's say 75% back to 80%? No problem (an I2C input nearly always has hysteresis), and I wouldn't even be sure it is real: after all, you did connect a probe...

Comment: If your talking about the photographic reflection then that has nothing to do with this stack. However, the solution for photographing reflective surfaces is to set up two lights at 45 degrees (one at each side) and shoot through a black felt screen in front. The reflection is then the black felt and non-illuminated lens rather than your fingers .

Comment: no i am talking about the reflection (unless you believe it is not a result of an actual signal reflection?) on the signal on the falling edge of Channel 1 (Yellow Signal).

Comment: There is a small disturbance at the same moment in the blue line?. Are you realy sure what you see is a reflection? Is this a one-time capture? On an old-scholl oscilloscope you would see an aggregated picture, which might give some clue about the repeatability.

Answer (score 2):

Non-monotonic edges on the I<sup>2</sup>C SDA line are rarely a problem. During the main part of any transfer, the data is clocked by the SCL line, and this occurs only when the SDA line is stable.

The only time a falling edge on SDA is significant is when it is used to signal the I<sup>2</sup>C "start" condition — falling edge on SDA while SCL is high.

There is one situation in which this could present a problem. Some devices require a "repeated start" condition — a "start" that is not preceded by a "stop" — in order to properly implement certain read operations.

A glitch during such a repeated start could be interpreted by the device as a "stop" followed by a "start", which would leave it in the wrong state.

The glitch you show is really tiny, and as Wouter says, many I<sup>2</sup>C devices incorporate Schmitt triggers (hysteresis) in order to mitigate glitches like this.

Any sort of low-pass filtering will also help. A low-value series resistor (on the order of a few tens of ohws) located near the master device, in conjunction with the bus's distributed capacitance, will form such a filter. Experiment to find the best value for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Add a series resistor 22 Ohm or 33 Ohm. Simulate the line in Hyperlynx if necessary.

Edit: I see that someone doesn't like my answer here.

I think my answer is correct. Reflections in the signal like the one presented above can be significantly removed when a series termination resistor is added which deacreases the edge rise time/fall time which cause the reflection to be smaller. In case of overshoots one can also add a Schottky diode on a line connected to the supply, but this should be present inside a chip which uses I2C.

One has to also watch out for the voltage limits (IH,IL) for the I2C (and in general CMOS inputs. Too high series resistance can cause problems when it's not paired with a correct value of a pull-up.